# jQuery datatable plugin not providing desired result

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I added required js and css file into client side code but I'm getting the proper results. In resulting webpage, I'm getting a table with content, but I can't see option for search, sort and pagination. Where did I make a mistake?

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-icon.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/themify-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/flag-icon.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/cs-skin-elastic.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/lib/datatable/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-select.less">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/scss/style.css">

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

        var table = $('#TEST').DataTable({
        });
</script>

<div class="content mt-3">
  <div class="animated fadeIn">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <a href="clients.aspx" style="color: olive;">Add New</a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <table id="TEST" class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
              <thead>
                <tr>

                  <th>Application Name</th>
                  <th>Customer Name</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>AMC</th>
                  <th>Edit</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <asp:Repeater ID="r7" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>

                      <td>
                        <%#Eval("app_name") %>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <%#Eval("Cname") %>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <%#Eval("status") %>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <%#Eval("AMC") %>
                      </td>

                      <td><a href="Project_edit.aspx?id=<%#Eval(" id ") %>" style="color:rgb(50,205,50)" ;>Edit</a></td>
                      <%-- <td><a href=" %>" style="color:rgb(255,0,0)";>Delete</a>
                        </td--%>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:Repeater>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include jQuery which is required by jQuery DataTables.

Include the following line **before** jQuery DataTables JS file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
```